# Interpreting Robocopy logs

Tags: robocopy

I'm using robocopy to copy a folder:

```
Robocopy "F:\Users" "G:\Users" /MIR /R:5 /W:15 /MT:32 /V /XA:O /XJD /LOG:G:\Backup.log
```

What's the meaning of these terms in the log?:

```
Modified
Attrib
etc.
```

I found some sites explaining some of these, but not all of them. Please see picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's saying the target has been updated with a modified version, and/or a version that has had attributes changed etc...

For example `file1.accdb` on `f:\users` has replaced the version in `g:\users`, because it's newer.

Comment: The question is that the log I get when I add the /L switch are clear, they compare source and target OK, but I'd like to understand the log get when I just do a normal robocopy, they seem a little different.  Thanks for your answer.  I'll check this a bit more and come back if needed.